# Official aws-cli image does not accept scripts commands from gitlab

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

I am using **amazon/aws-cli:2.2.40** in a gitlab pipeline to publish a static site on a S3.

```yaml
deploy_front: 
  image: amazon/aws-cli:2.2.40
  variables:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:  $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
  stage: publish
  script:
    - s3 sync ./front/build s3://some-bucket-name
```

ends up in

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
accessanalyzer                           | acm                                     
acm-pca                                  | alexaforbusiness                        
amp                                      | amplify                                 
amplifybackend                           | apigateway
.......                                    ..........
```

I managed to replicate this error by running `docker run -it amazon/aws-cli:2.2.40 aws s3` locally. However `docker run -it amazon/aws-cli:2.2.40 s3` works so I do not understand why I get the same error no matter what I use in `script`. Is it a some escaping issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the `amazon/aws-cli` image's entrypoint being: `/usr/local/bin/aws`. When you run `aws` by itself locally, it'll return the help message and give a 252 exit code. To [override the entrypoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#overriding-the-entrypoint-of-an-image), you do so like this:

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - aws s3 help
```

Comment: this was incredibly frustrating and your answer solved my problem, thanks!